# How to know how big an unmapped folder is on Visual Studio TFS Source Control?

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2013, source-control-explorer

I want to know the file size in total of a folder before I get latest for a folder on `Source Control` when connected to a TFS Team Project.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [TFS Administrators Toolkit for Visual Studio 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/33713c5d-31a3-44b3-ae94-3c413e6b21c7) to show the folder sizes including those that have not been downloaded yet.

[image]